# Running lightweight SELinux policy in production

Tags: selinux

I'd like to take advantage of SELinux ability to restrict a group of Linux processes. The group is unprivileged users with high enough UID (say, >1000). This I want to do on a shared hosting server, where many different customers run their PHP scripts. Currently, SELinux is off.

More specifically, I'd like to **ban creation of symlinks** and perhaps a few other similar rules, due to various symlink-related attacks, for example see

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=linux+symlink+race

I think such use of SELinux is possible using a rule in base policy, a short rule that does something like (pseudo code):

```
"allow everything that SELinux Off does"
neverallow $source_type $target_type : lnk_file write;
```

where in **source_type** and **target_type** somehow the targeted group of unix users will be specified (sorry if that is wrong, I'm not very familiar with SELinux yet).

*However, this is pretty much the only thing I want SELinux to do.*

I'd rather not use full default policy distributed by Redhat or other Linux distributions, for that is very restrictive and could lead to a lot of problems with currently working applications.

**Is there some problem with running SELinux with so permissive a policy? Or, is there some other preferred way to achieve this kind of restriction?**